# iOS JSON parse trouble

Tags: ios, json, nsjsonserialization

How should I parse JSONs with format:

```
{
"1": {
    "name": "Бекон",
    "unit": "гр."
},
"2": {
    "name": "Бульон куриный",
    "unit": "ст."
}
```

}

and:

```
{
  "recipeCode" : "00001",
  "inCategory" : "12",
  "recipe" : "Зимний тыквенный суп",
  "difficulty" : 2,
  "personCount" : 4,
  "prepHour" : 1,
  "prepMin" : 30,
  "comments" : "При подаче добавить сметану, крутоны и присыпать сыром",
  "ingredients" : {
    "2" : 3,
    "11" : 2,
    "13" : 1,
    "14" : 2,
    "19" : 1
  }
}
```

The second one I even didn't try... But with the first one I have some problems. I do this:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Ingredients" ofType:@"json"];
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *ingredients = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

and than I have **ingredient** dictionary with two key/value pairs. Both of them contains **key** "1" and **value** "1 key/value pairs" and nothing about "name" or "unit" values.

Any help how to correctly parse such JSONs

Comment: When I execute your code the JSON is correctly parsed. Please provide a better illustration of why it does not work for you. Can you NSLog the dictionary and include your output.

Comment: NSLog shows everything (but "debug window" didn't show).. ok, this works, but how to read this internal data?

Comment: How do you want to display data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are parsing it correctly,and what you will have output will be there in the dictionary

The parsing gives output as **objects as NSDictionary** and **array as NSArray**

so in your case the key 1 and key 2 have value a NSDictionary itself

[image]

```
NSDictionary *dict1 = [ingredients objectForKey:@"1"];
NSDictionary *dict2 = [ingredients objectForKey:@"2"];
```

and value as

```
NSString *name=[dict1 objectForKey:@"name"];
NSString *unit=[dict1 objectForKey:@"unit"];
```

Comment: yeah!!! I understand how it works. Thanks! So the second file is a dictionary and **ingredients** is an object with dictionary in it. Am I right?

Comment: yeah thats it.If it is an object representation {} then it is dictionary and if array [] then it is nsarray returned